# How to Fetch values from WP database based on selected option value by onchange using PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, wpdb

I have retrieve data from WP db and display in select list.
But I cant able to store the selected option value in php variable. And I cant able to display data based on selected value. The data should be displayed when the select box is changed (onChange)

```
<select id="mySelect" name="taskOption">
<option>Choose Your Area</option>
<?php
      $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); 
        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            echo '<option  value="'.$result->id.'">'.$result->area_name.'</option>';
        }
      ?>
                 </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below example to use Ajax in wordpress. [This](https://paulund.co.uk/using-ajax-wordpress) article explains it quite nicely.

1. Main jquery function to use

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-scripts', url-to-your-file/plugin-ajax.js', __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

   jQuery(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mySelect').on( 'change' , function(){
       var newValue = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: ajaxurl, // use ajax_params.ajax_url if using in plugin
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
               action: 'yourFunction',
               newValue: newValue
           },
           success: function(response) {
               console.log(response);
           },
           error: function(errorThrown){
               console.log(errorThrown);
           }    
         })
       })
      })
     });
   ```
2. Hook your function

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_yourFunction', 'yourFunction' );
   function yourFunction(){
       $newValue = $_POST['newValue'];
       //Query whatever you want to with the $newValue
   }
   ```

**If you're using it in a plugin then you'll need to localize your script first.**

```
//Localize the script for ajax purposes
wp_localize_script(
     'ajax-scripts',
'ajax_params',
array( 
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, but I cant able use this variable " $newValue" in other function

Comment: you can use the $_POST[''] value in your query

Comment: I have tried a lot. I want to use that variable in another function. pls post the example please

Comment: Lets continue here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68741/wordpress-ajax

Comment: using this setting helped for me...   url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',